# How to import a field from MarketWatch in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I would like to scrape the `EX-DIVIDEND DATE` field from MarketWatch, where in my example the date is "Nov 15, 2018". This is the link:

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/inn.pd

Until now, I had used the following code:

```
=index(ImporthtML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/inn.pd","list",14),13,1)
```

It worked just fine, but it seems something has got changed in MarketWatch and I am now unable to figure it out just by guessing different numbers in the query since I do not understand this language.

Can you provide me with a formula to scrape just this field? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/inn.pd", 
 "list", 23), 13, 1),
 "Ex-Dividend Date", "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'True' date option (ie Number format, not Text):

```
=1*mid(index(ImporthtML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/inn.pd","list",23),13,0),18,50)
```

The information you seek was effectively moved from ColumnN to ColumnX (10 lists/columns inserted before it), hence `14` > `24`, but remained in the same 'row' (`13`).

If much the same were to happen again a little trial and error should be all that is required for you to track down again the information you seek.